# vh/vw parameters not working within iframe

Tags: css, wordpress, iframe, wordpress-theming

We run a small theme shop with several theme demos and have looked everywhere for some sort of plugin that will properly render our themes on both desktop and mobile devices. I'm not sure there's any other way to do it, but every plugin we've tried uses iframe functionality to display theme demos. This work fine except on themes that utilize vh/vw CSS, on fullscreen headers, for example. For whatever reason the background images stretch way out of proportion, rendering the entire demo unscrollable.

We've tried everything we can think of, [like setting media queries to specify width/height](https://gist.github.com/pburtchaell/e702f441ba9b3f76f587) but nothing is working. It's only an issue on mobile devices, specifically iOS devices - but likely Android devices too.

Surely we're not the only ones using vh/vw CSS on theme demos so I'm just wondering how other developers are getting around this. Any suggestions, tips & tricks would be appreciated!

For testing purposes, here's a link to one of our themes on a staging site, specifically using the [FBar plugin from CodeCanyon](https://codecanyon.net/item/fbar-responsive-wordpress-demo-switch-bar-plugin/5117122). And yes, we've tried reaching out to their support - they've been no help, unfortunately.

http://besuperfly.staging.wpengine.com/demo?theme=Anthem

Comment: what do you mean, "theme demos"?

Comment: Questions should be self-contained and not rely on external links. Put the relevant code in your question if you can.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not a "self-contained" question. I can't put the relevant code here - it's something you actually have to see for yourself to see what's happening. But thanks for the reply, I guess.

Comment: In my last resort to find a solution, maybe I've incorrectly assumed there were people here that could help me. Theme demos are... well, demos of our themes. Not sure how else to explain it.